# React Presentation Component Not Receiving MapDispatchToProps From Smart Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is really strange & awkward & I can't seem to make sense of whats wrong here.

Here is the 'smart' component:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TemplateParent from "../component/svg/TemplateParent";
import { setInitialViewBox } from "../modcon/Actions";

const mapStateToProps = ({ svgTemplateState }) => {
    return({
        renderType : "Template Selection",
        svgTemplateState : svgTemplateState
    });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return({
        dispatchSetInitialViewBox : ( viewBoxCoOrdinates ) => {
            dispatch( setInitialViewBox( viewBoxCoOrdinates ));
        }
    });
};

const C_TemSelectionSVGTemplate = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( TemplateParent );
export default C_TemSelectionSVGTemplate;
```

And Here is the 'presentation' component:

```
import React from "react";
import { calcViewBoxCentre } from "../../modcon/GlobalAPI";

const TemplateParent = React.createClass({
componentDidUpdate : function(){
    let getEleDimension = this.gEle.getBBox(),
        viewboxValue = calcViewBoxCentre( getEleDimension, 1.75 );
    /*** ERROR IS HERE: this.props.dispatchSetInitialViewBox is not a function ***/
    this.props.dispatchSetInitialViewBox( viewboxValue );
},

render : function(){
    /*** the below console logs only shows two props: `renderType` & `svgTemplateState` ***/
    console.log( this.props );
    return(
        <g className = "templateParent"
            ref = {( g ) => this.gEle = g }>
        </g>
    );
}
});
```

I cant seem to figure out why the `mapDispatchToProps` is not being passed as props to the component `TemplateParent`.

As requested, here is the action creator `setInitialViewBox`:

```
export const setInitialViewBox = ( viewBox ) => {
    return({
        type : SET_INITIAL_VIEWBOX,
        svgPayload : {
            defaultTab : {
                viewBox : viewBox,
                scale : 1
            },
            bodyTab : {
                viewBox : viewBox,
                scale : 1
            },
            sleeveTab : {
                viewBox : viewBox,
                scale : 1
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Not necessarily related but I take it you are exporting the TemplateParent component?

Comment: Yes I am. I had to simplify the presentation component `TemplateParent`, as there are a few calculations going on in there. But yes, it is being `export default TemplateParent`

Comment: Show us the `setInitialViewBox` action

Comment: My sincere apologies, it turns out that the component was being used in two different places. Once where its connected to the `smart component` (as above) & the second time, as a plain child presentation component. They both are virtually called at the same time, for updating different sections, hence the confusion. Many thanks to all for the review of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I read your code and I'm not catching your problem,
but i have some notes:

You should not pass your parameter `viewBoxCoOrdinates` in the mapDispatchToProps.
you can check **bindActionCreators** may be the solution
exemple :

```
import {bindActionCreators} from 'react-redux';
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return({
        dispatchSetInitialViewBox : bindActionCreators(viewBoxCoOrdinates, dispatch)
        }
    });
};
```

And you can access your function by props.dispatchSetInitialViewBox();

more infos : [**bindActionCreators**](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, Im not sure what benefit this brings to the code. In my code, `TemplateParent` is redux aware so I dont think there should be any problem with passing `viewBoxCoOrdinates`. Please correct me if Im missing something. I've read Dan's page linked above, however, fail to see the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shorthand notation to map dispatch to props like this:

```
export default connect( mapStateToProps, { setInitialViewBox })( TemplateParent );
```

And in your component you can do `this.props.setInitialViewBox`.